# Order Confirmation Email template

Tags: magento2, email-templates, order-email, stores

I am adding products in English store view on calling payment information API i switched the store and give store_code arabic in param

```
/rest/V1/carts/mine/payment-information?store_code=ar
```

Now when this api successfully runs it gives me order confirmation email in English and stores store id in order table  for enlish store.

Note : I Select the option

**Stores > Configurations >  Customers > Account Sharing** to global